# How can I find a word and print it along with his next word in Python

Tags: python, pandas, string, loops, multiple-columns

I have the following list:

```
pre = ["unable to", "would not", "was not", "did not", "there is not", "could not", "failed to"]
```

From dataframe column I want to find texts that have the words of the list in order to generate a new column that can print these words along with the next word, for example, in a column cell there is the following text `WOULD NOT PRIME CORRECTLY DURING VIRECTOMY.`, I want a new column that prints the following: `WOULD NOT PRIME`.

I have tried something like this

```
def matcher(Event_Description):
    for i in pre:
        if i in Event_Description:
            return i + 1
    return "Not found"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over every prefix in the list and check for the prefix using `.find()`. If it is found, you can change the prefix to the case of `event` and append the next word. Like this:

```
def matcher(event):
    pres = ["unable to", "would not", "was not", "did not", "there is not", "could not", "failed to"]
    for pre in pres:
        i = event.lower().find(pre)
        if i != -1:
            return ' '.join([pre.upper() if event.isupper() else pre, *event[i + len(pre) + 1:].split(' ')[0]])
    return "Not found"
```

If you want to include the next two words, just change this line:

```
return ' '.join([pre.upper() if event.isupper() else pre, *event[i + len(pre) + 1:].split(' ')[0]])
```

to a slice like this:

```
return ' '.join([pre.upper() if event.isupper() else pre, *event[i + len(pre) + 1:].split(' ')[0:2]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply Michael. If I want to print more than one next word, for example the next 2 words how can I modify what you shared?

Comment: @VictorLeon I've updated my answer to include a solution to that.